# How to create tsconfig.json file in angular2 project?

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, tsconfig

I have created one angular2 project using npm.
I was referring this link:
[Angular2 Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

I succeessfully created the `package.json` file using `npm init` command.
But I didnt find any command to create `tsconfig.json` file.
I am not sure that should I create that file using command or using editor?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoking the TypeScript compiler with the `init` option will create a new `tsconfig.json` in the current directory

```
tsc --init
```

Answer (score 7):

To complement the Vadim's answer, the tsc command is available after having installed TypeScript:

```
$ npm install -g typescript
```

You can also use some parameters with this comment:

```
$ tsc --init --experimentalDecorators
      --moduleResolution node --target ES5
      --sourceMap --module system --removeComments
```

This way, you're very close to what Angular.io uses for this samples.

You can then remove the `outDir` and `rootDir` entries if not needed. Moreover an entry isn't generated this way. You can add it manually in the generaed `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry